# How can I edit an .ejs file in the intellij idea

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ejs

I am trying to edit an .ejs File in the intellij idea
I already installed the ejs plugin and restarted intellij but I can't open/edit the .ejs file

I am working on a node.js project

Comment: Please add some more description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is though you have installed the plugin intelliJ still doesn't know that the plugin you installed(EJS plugin) should be associated with `*.ejs` files.

Do the following to let intelliJ know of that.

- Go **File -> Settings**.
- Type `File Types`
- Open ***File Types*** tab.
- Navigate to to the EJS plugin listed under ***Recognized File Types***.
- Add `*.ejs` into ***Registered Patterns*** below.

[image]

Comment: EJS plug-in adds this association automatically, no manual adding is needed. Could be that EJS plug-in is disabled or doesn't work (like it was installed manually for the incompatible version). The user should check that the plug-in is enabled.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yh.. if so the problem should be that. :)) Anyway what can make ejs plugin incompatible??

Comment: Plugins have compatibility versions specified, when IDE installs a plug-in it downloads the compatible version automatically, if user downloads the plug-in version from the site manually (as a zip file), he usually gets the latest version which can be for the next IDE version (2017, available in EAP), so the plug-in will not load in 2016 version. It's also possible that users runs Community Edition which will not load the plug-in because CE has no JS support.

Comment: It was installed and active but not working. anyway I am using webstorm now. but thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have intellij detect *.ejs as *.html files to provide autocompletion for those files you can:

Go File -> Settings.
Type File Types
Open File Types tab.
click on HTML.
Click on + under File name patterns
Add *.ejs in the file name pattern list.